# Throughput of the network in the given scenario

Tags: throughput

Suppose Host A wants to send a large file to Host B. The path from Host A to Host B has 3 links of rates:

- R1 = 512 Kbps
- R2 = 2 Mbps
- R3 = 1 Mbps

What is the throughput for the file transfer (in Kbytes per minute)?

According to me the whole link is equivalent to a 512kbps link
and according to that the efficiency = 512*60/8 (KBytes/min).

Is the logic and answer correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: How are packets shared across the links?

Comment: no info is given this is the complete question.

Comment: Explain how you came up with your answer.

Comment: i compared this with a typical pipeline structure where for large no. of instructions the lag depends on the slowest segment and hence here R1 will be the one.

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework question (and a bad one at that as one must *assume* how packets are distributed across the various links)

Comment: no this is not a homework question this is a question that was asked in one of my exams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the limited information provided and taking the most basic networking view you are correct, you will always be limited by the slowest link in a network with a single route from A to B. In reality most topologies are redundant, all file transport protocols have overhead and most networks have congestion.

Also you look to have assumed 8 bits in a byte and 60 seconds in a minute :)

Comment: but there are 8 bits in a byte and 60 seconds in a minute..

Comment: Yup which is why you are probably correct! Why do you assume you are wrong?

Comment: because you said assumed one cannot assume what is true. It is what it is....

Comment: One can assume anything one wants, that is the point of assumption, unfortunately that is a little of the point of this SE site. Does my response answer the question? I have never met anybody ever in my 10 year professional career that using KB/min as a measurement, that is purely an academic twist, hence my slightly tongue in cheek reply.

Comment: i guess there is a first time for everything and one generally assumes those things that are ambiguous  and not inherently clear.